# Can't set URLRequest Authorization Header

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift3, ios10

Since swift 3 update I change my requests from NSMutableURLRequest to URLRequest. After that all my requests stopped worked due invalid credentials problem. Already tried and search everything. My service continue same as before and tested my requests from a request simulator and went fine.

```
let url : NSString = "http://url.service.com/method?param=\(name)" as NSString

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setAuthorizationHeader()

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in

    do {

        //something

    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        //something
    }

}.resume()
```

My setAuthorizationHeader() extension

```
extension URLRequest {

    mutating func setAuthorizationHeader(){

        let data = "user:password".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let base64 = data?.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        setValue("Basic \(base64)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your String interpolation it is probably passing an optional string forHTTPHeaderField

Comment: try `if let base64 = data?.base64EncodedString(options: []) {
        setValue("Basic \(base64)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") }`

Comment: @LeoDabus It worked! Thank you. Can you explain whats the difference? I see any difference.

Comment: @LeoDabus and I wasn't doing that already? Write on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not unwrapping your String variable before doing the String interpolation and thus passing an Optional string description to forHTTPHeaderField. [Check Proposal: SE-0054.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) Just make sure you safely unwrap your optional using if let:

```
if let base64 = data?.base64EncodedString(options: []) {
    setValue("Basic \(base64)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
}
```